# Error al trasladar funcion de vb6 a VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6

Estoy trasladando una función que está programado en VB6.

```
Public Function funPeriodoActual() As String
    Dim strCadena As String
    Dim strConexion As String
    Private cnConexion As ADODB.Connection
    Private rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Private strBD As String
    Dim strActual As String

    strActual = "0"

    strBD = "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\BC_PM.mdb"
    strConexion = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strBD & ";Persist Security Info=FALSE;Jet OLEDB"

    Set cnConexion = New ADODB.Connection
    cnConexion.ConnectionString = strConexion
    cnConexion.Open

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs.ActiveConnection = cnConexion

    rs.Open "qryUltimas_dos_BD", cnConexion, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable     
    rs.MoveFirst
    strActual = rs.Fields("PK_HD") 
    rs.Close

    Set rs = Nothing
    cnConexion.Close
    Set cnConexion = Nothing
    funPeriodoActual = strActual
End Function
```

Mi Código para VB.NET

```
Public Function funPeriodoActual() As String
        'Dim strCadena As String
        'Dim strConexion As String
        Dim rs As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
        Dim strActual As String
        Dim oleComand As OleDb.OleDbCommand

        strActual = "0"
        strBD = "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\BC_PM.mdb"
        cnConexion = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
        cnConexion.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & strBD & "';Jet OLEDB:Database;"
        cnConexion.Open()
        oleComand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("qryUltimas_dos_BD", cnConexion)
        rs = oleComand.ExecuteReader()

        strActual = CStr(rs.Item("PK_HD"))
        rs.Close()    
        rs = Nothing
        cnConexion.Close()    
        Return strActual
 End Function
```

Al ejecutar la función me arroja el error :

> El formato de la cadena de inicialización no se ajusta a la
>   especificación que comienza en el índice 82.

Igual estoy trasladando de forma erronea los datos. Agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: Pareceria estar mal la cadena de conexion. Igual, para lo que estas haciendo, alcanza con que hagas un ExecuteScalar en lugar de un reader.

Comment: Podría ser que falta parámetros, de acuerdo a este [link](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2003/) la cadena se arma de esta manera: `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;User Id=admin;
Password=;`

Answer (score 0):

Solo para complementar...

Las cadenas de conexión para OLEDB las puedes consultar aquí: 
https://www.connectionstrings.com/net-framework-data-provider-for-ole-db/

En tu línea de conexión:

> cnConexion.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" & strBD & "';Jet OLEDB:Database;"

Me parece que esta de más la comilla simple (Source='"....) para poner la dirección.

Como sugerencia, te recomiendo usar el ConnectionString.config de .NET para almacenar tu información de conexión.